# Random Image Url with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, random

I've created this code to random show an url on the same link. 
This is the file prova.php:

```
<?php
$file = "foto.txt";
// Convert the text fle into array and get text of each line in each array index
$file_arr = file($file);
// Total number of linesin file
$num_lines = count($file_arr);
// Getting the last array index number by subtracting 1 as the array index starts from 0
$last_arr_index = $num_lines - 1;
// Random index number
$rand_index = rand(0, $last_arr_index);
// random text from a line. The line will be a random number within the indexes of the array
$rand_text = $file_arr[$rand_index];
echo $rand_text;
   $file = $rand_text;

    // write out
    $type = 'image/jpg';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
?>
```

This is the .htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^foto.jpg prova.php [L]
```

Then I go to http://mysite/folder/foto.jpg but my image don't load. Wordpress tell me that page don't exist.
Instead if I go to prova.php, I see the correct link inside the file.

What is wrong?

Comment: is `echo $rand_text;` really there? because that will break things.

Comment: .htaccess inner folder `folder` ?

Comment: The rand_text is right working... no problem with it. The file php give me the right url. So no problem with extracting the random line from the file. The problem, i think is with the rewriting rules. Yes the htaccess is in the subfolder. Not in the site root.

Answer (score 1):

Use an htaccess tester (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

As written, your htaccess doesn't work with your URL scheme. This rule will only be applied for "http://test.com/foto.jpg", or whatever your domain is.

If foto.jpg is supposed to be in "folder", you can change your htaccess to read `^folder/foto.jpg`.

---

EDIT

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Your rules here
RewriteRule ^wp-content/folder/foto.jpg prova.php [L]

# This should be last
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: mmm no.. the htacces is in the same subfolder of prova.php. If I add the subfolder to htaccess I get a 404 error. All files are in the same subfolder.

Comment: In WP, you may run into trouble putting this htaccess file in the subdirectory. 

The default framework htaccess includes these 3 lines:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

If the path is not directly to a file or directory that the web server can see, you get shunted into the WP framework routing system via `index.php`.  I would guess that's why you get "Page does not exist" instead of "File not found".

Comment: I've deleted the htaccess inside subfolder and added this line   `RewriteRule ^wp-content/folder/foto.jpg prova.php [L]` to the root htaccess, after the `Rewriterule ./index.php` but it is the same.

Comment: Where is prova.php located? The path `http://test.com/wp-content/folder/foto.jpg` will redirect to `http://test.com/prova.php` with this rule.  Is that correct?

Comment: Second question, is that line before or after the default WP rules?

Comment: No my need that php is read like an image. It musn't redirect to php file. It must read php file like a jpg. This is the block code in htacces `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-content/newletter/foto.jpg prova.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188709/discussion-between-bluemoon6790-and-bigblack).